# jQuery DataTables - Custom Column Visiblity

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I like to use [jQuery DataTable Plugin](https://www.datatables.net/) and want to create something like this-

[image: one]

And when anyone click on **"Column visibility"** button, they will see like this-

[image: www]

But I don't like to have **Global search Button** and Pagination on top (because I have already a pagination in the bottom).

I only want that button.

So, what I have done is -

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var dataTable =  $('#employee-grid').DataTable(
{
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    //ajax: "employee-grid-data.php", // json datasource for AJAX Data

    "ajax":
    {
        "url": "employee-grid-data.php",
        //"type": 'POST',
        "data": function ( d )              //Sending Custom Data for manupulating with elements out of the table
                {
                    d.myKey = "myValue";
                    // d.custom = $('#myInput').val();
                    // etc
                },
    },

    //"pagingType": "full_numbers", //Adding Last and First in Pagination
    stateSave: true,
    "language":{                    //Custom Message Setting
                    "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",    //Customizing menu Text
                    "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",             //Customizing zero record text - filtered
                    "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",           //Customizing showing record no
                    "infoEmpty": "No records available",                //Customizing zero record message - base
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"   //Customizing filtered message
                },
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],        //For customizing number of data sets per page

    dom: 'l<"toolbar">frtip Bfrtip',        //"Bfrtip" is for column visiblity

    initComplete:   function()  //Adding Custom button in Tools
                    {
                        $("div.toolbar").html('<button type="button" onclick="addNewEntry()">Add a New Record</button>');
                    },
    buttons:    [                   //Column Visiblity Buttons
                    {
                        extend: 'colvis',
                        collectionLayout: 'fixed three-column',
                        postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ]
                    }
                ],
});
});
```

More Preciously-

```
    dom: 'l<"toolbar">frtip Bfrtip',
    buttons:    [                   //Column Visiblity Buttons
                    {
                        extend: 'colvis',
                        collectionLayout: 'fixed three-column',
                        postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ]
                    }
                ],
```

But I am finding something like this-

[image: asd]

So, I want only **Green Round** and not **Red Round**.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Option [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) can be a little confusing at first, but simply put, each letter in it is a DataTables feature. Also order of the letters describe their positioning on the page.

- `B` - Buttons,
- `f` - filtering input
- `r` - processing display element
- `t` - table
- `i` - informational panel
- `p` - pagination control

There are other letters and HTML markup supported. See [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option and [Buttons - `dom` parameter](http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/#dom-parameter) 
pages for more information.

Use the code below:

```js
var dataTable =  $('#employee-grid').DataTable({
    // ... skipped ... 
    dom: 'Brtip',        
    buttons: [
       {
          extend: 'colvis',
          collectionLayout: 'fixed three-column',
          postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ]
       }
    ]
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxndhL1e/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks "Bfrtip" is perfect for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option of `dataTable` while initializing as below:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
});
```

You can see **[Source/Demo here](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html)**

More Precise **[explanation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)**